# Parallelize distance calculation method with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, distance, python-multiprocessing

This question is related to the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750397/optimizing-point-circle-distance-method) I posted days ago; I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288595/multiprocessing-using-pool-map-on-a-function-defined-in-a-class) about the issue related to `multiprocessing` pickling with instance methods. The problem is that I did not understand how to apply the solution provided to my case:

```
def _pickle_method(method):
    # Author: Steven Bethard
    # http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/552476-why-cant-you-pickle-instancemethods
    func_name = method.im_func.__name__
    obj = method.im_self
    cls = method.im_class
    cls_name = ''
    if func_name.startswith('__') and not func_name.endswith('__'):
        cls_name = cls.__name__.lstrip('_')
    if cls_name:
        func_name = '_' + cls_name + func_name
    return _unpickle_method, (func_name, obj, cls)

def _unpickle_method(func_name, obj, cls):
    # Author: Steven Bethard
    # http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/552476-why-cant-you-pickle-instancemethods
    for cls in cls.mro():
        try:
            func = cls.__dict__[func_name]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    return func.__get__(obj, cls)

copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _pickle_method, _unpickle_method)

class Circle(Feature):
# Stuff...
    def __points_distance(self,points):
        xa = n.array([self.xc,self.yc]).reshape((1,2))
        d = n.abs(dist.cdist(points,xa) - self.radius)
        return d

def points_distance(self,points,pool=None):
    if pool:
        return pool.map(self.__points_distance,points)
    else:
        return self.__points_distance(points)
```

This gives `ValueError: XA must be a 2-dimensional array` error when running this:

```
import tra.features as fts
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

points = np.random.random(size=(1000,2))
circle_points = np.random.random(size=(3,2))

feature = fts.Circle(circle_points)

pool = mp.Pool()
ds = feature.points_distance(points,pool=pool)
```

but it (obviously) work when doing:

```
pool = None
ds = feature.points_distance(points,pool=pool)
```

Any clues?

This is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750397/optimizing-point-circle-distance-method) (I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11727096/1334711) implementation) because the method is used inside another class that instantiate the `Circle` class and calls its `points_distance` method. In any case another difference is that `points_distance` method uses `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` that expects (n,2)-shaped `numpy.ndarray`. It works when using the serial version but raises the exception I mentioned when used in parallel. I suppose there's a caveat of arguments passing with cPickle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'> when using python's multiprocessing Pool.map()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma)

Comment: @User thanks for the help. I already checked the answer you provide but at the moment is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `points` array you pass to `pool.map` has a shape of (1000, 2). When `pool.map` splits it up to pass as the `points` argument to `__points_distance`, *that* array only has shape (2,).

Try adding `points.shape = (1, 2)` to the body of `__points_distance` before the call to `cdist`.

Comment: I'm a bit new to multiprocessing, but it seems like the way it splits your (1000, 2) array into a thousand (2,) arrays isn't a good use of numpy's capabilities. Maybe there's a way to, say, split a (1000000, 2) array into a thousand (1000, 2) arrays and send each of those to a worker.

Comment: I guess the obvious way is to reshape `points` to (10, 100, 2) and then `vstack` the results together....

Comment: this is a good point. I'm quite worried that it should be done manually using `multiprocessing.Queue` and `multiprocessing.Process`. I think on that I bit waiting for possibly other answers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably pre-splitting the array before giving it to `pool.map` and then inserting the chunks in a list could be a solution. Let's say using `numpy.split`.

Comment: I think you're getting a bit far from your original question ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think there is quite a bit of confusion here so I'm not sure I understand the problem.

The exception `NameError: global name 'pool' is not defined` is not due to a pickling issue but rather to a scoping problem.

The method cannot find `pool` in its scope. Try fixing it by passing the `pool` reference to the method.

Other thing:

```
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
```

The `cpu_count()` call is redundant as the Pool already spawns as many workers as CPUs you have by default.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I solved the scope issue but I'm getting another Exception related to `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`. If you want you can edit your answer if you know what's going on.

Comment: I'd rather prefer you to close this question as solved and open a new one where you explain the new issue you encounter. As other people might read this question would be easier for them to have a separate context.

Answer (score 0):

The `pool` variable is defined outside of `Circle` class, so `points_distance() will be unable to find`pool` in its namespace:

Add a constructor to Circle or Feature which accepts a `pool`, and pass the pool you want to use to `RansacFeature`, which I assume instantiates `Circle`s for you.